# how can separate result of object function?

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I have a LINQ query in  function, like below code:

```
public object RetrieveFday(DateTime _dt)
    {
 var fp = from f in RSC.tbl_FoodPlan join food in RSC.tbl_Food
                              on f.FoodID equals food.FoodID
                              where f.Day == _dt
                              select new 
                              {
                                 FoodName= food.Name,
                                 Fholiday= f.HoliDay
                              };


            return fp;
   }
```

now I call this function in other place, I want to get result and separate them to display every one in different label, when call the function and get result I cant read property of them:

```
var test = RetrieveFday(dt);
```

how can read the property in result that into test?

Comment: why are you returning object, while the LINQ query results are IQueryable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) are not meant to use as a return types, so just create a new class to hold your projection data:

```
public class FoodNameAndHoliday
{
    public string FoodName { get; set; }
    public string Fholiday { get; set; }
}
```

And modify your `RetrieveFday` function to use your class in the `select`:

```
public IEnumerable<FoodNameAndHoliday> RetrieveFday(DateTime _dt)
{
     var fp = from f in RSC.tbl_FoodPlan join food in RSC.tbl_Food
                          on f.FoodID equals food.FoodID
                          where f.Day == _dt
                          select new FoodNameAndHoliday
                          {
                             FoodName= food.Name,
                             Fholiday= f.HoliDay
                          };
      return fp;
}
```

And you can then use your function like:

```
var test = RetrieveFday(dt);
foreach(var item in test)
{
    DoSomethingWith(item.FoodName);
    DoSomethingWith(item.Fholiday);
}
```

Comment: In addition to @nemesv answer - if you still must use anonymous types and can't afford to create a class, try to return `IEnumerable<dynamic>` instead of `object`'